# Function to check if it's holiday in jquery by date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I'm trying to make a function in jquery which checks if a given date is a holiday according to my database. I have created the function:

```
IsAHoliday(date)
```

Here is my code:

```
function IsAHoliday(date) {
    var datum = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var dataString = 'action='+ datum;
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'include/datumPraznik.php',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(r)
        {
            return r;
        } 
    });
}
```

With this code i can't execute something like

```
if(IsAHoliday(date)) {
```

How could i achieve this ?

---

EDIT: Here is my datumPraznik.php

```html
<?php
    include_once('db-config.php');

    $datum = $_REQUEST['action'];
    $stmt=$db_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM praznici WHERE praznik_datum=:datum');
    $stmt->execute(array(':datum'=>$datum));
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($row)>0)
    {
        $praznik = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $praznik = false;
    }
    echo $praznik;
?>
```

Comment: What is your datumPraznik.php code?

Comment: @Dino I have updated my question.

Comment: As the ajax call is async, you need to put your processing in the success part of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix my problem using your solutions but i've combined them and came to this solution.

1. I've made a global variable (array) and called ajax which returns **ALL HOLIDAY DATES** and stores them in the global variable.

```html
    var prazniciArray = [];
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'include/datumPraznik.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(rez)
            {
                praznici = rez;
                for (var i = 0; i < praznici.length; i++) {
                    prazniciArray.push(moment(praznici[i]));
                }
                $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").disabledDates(prazniciArray);
            } 
        });
    }
```

2. After that i could make the function:

```html
function IsHoliday(date) {
    var datum = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    if(jQuery.inArray(datum, praznici) !== -1)
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

3. datumPraznik.php

```html
<?php
    include_once('db-config.php');

    $stmt=$db_con->prepare('SELECT praznik_datum FROM praznici');
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $praznici = count($row);
    $prazniciarray = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $praznici; $i++) {    
        array_push($prazniciarray,$row[$i]["praznik_datum"]);
    }

    echo json_encode($prazniciarray);
?>
```

And my table looks like this:

```
praznik_id | praznik_ime  | praznik_datum   
-----------------------------------------
|     1    | Thanksgiving | 2017.07.01
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you could do get your PHP to return JSON so you can handle it with AJAX success function.

```
$datum = $_REQUEST['action'];
$stmt=$db_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM praznici WHERE praznik_datum='.$datum);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0){
    $praznik = true;
} else {
    $praznik = false;
}
return json_encode(array('praznik' => $praznik));
```

And your AJAX would be

```
$.post('include/datumPraznik.php', data, function(d) {
if(d.praznik === true) {
console.log('This is a holiday');
} else {
console.log('This is not a holiday');
}
});
```

So your updated function would be:

```
function isHoliday(date) {
 var datum = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 var data = 'action='+ datum;
    $.post('include/datumPraznik.php', data, function(d) {
    if(d.praznik === true) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    });

}
```

And use it as:

```
if(isHoliday(date) === true) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I have added one line `echo json_encode(array('praznik' => $praznik));` in datumPraznik.php, so running smth like site/datumPraznik.php?action=2017-06-26 gives the CORRECT result. 
However running the functtion IsHoliday("2017-06-26") in Inspect Element Console gives me UNDEFINED result...

Answer (score 0):

First, PHP needs to return JSON, so change:

```
echo $praznik;
```

to:

```
echo json_encode($praznik);
```

Second, since AJAX is asynchronous (you shouldn't use `async: false`), your function should take callbacks:

```
function IsAHoliday(date, truecb, falsecb) {
    var datum = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var dataString = 'action='+ datum;
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'include/datumPraznik.php',
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(r)
        {
            if (r) {
                truecb();
            } else {
                falsecb();
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

You then call it like:

```
IsAHoliday(date, function() {
    // stuff to do on holiday
}, function() {
    // stuff to do on non-holiday
});
```